# How to update the derived properties using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, binding

I have a few properties in a bindingList for a XtratreeList(DevExress) where a child node needs to show a parentnode'e property. I have the following code.

```
public abstract class ClassBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected static int initialId = 0;

    private int id;
    private int parentID;
    private string productName;
    private string productType;
    private string colorProductType;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if ( id == value )
                return;

            id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public int ParentID
    {
        get { return parentID; }
        set
        {
            if ( parentID == value )
                return;

            parentID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ParentID");
        }
    }

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return productName; }
        set
        {
            if ( productName == value )
                return;

            productName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    public string ProductType
    {
        get { return productType; }
        set
        {
            if ( productType == value )
                return;

            productType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductType");
            RaisePropertyChanged("ColorProductType");
        }
    }

    public string ColorProductType
    {
        get { return colorProductType ; }
        set
        {
            if (colorProductType == value)
                return;

            colorProductType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ColorProductType");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}`
```

My requirement is to have the `ColorProductType` property changed when the `ProductType` property changes, basically `ProductType` is a parent node property and `ColorProductType` - child's. So on changing the parent's property the child's need to be changed. I have both these properties bound to 2 text boxes. So changing the parent prop should change both textboxes, but the vice versa is not true.  `RaisePropertyChanged("ColorProductType");` within the parent is not working, `colorproducttype` is null, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

`RaisePropertyChanged` does not actually update the property. It simply signals the `PropertyChanged` event. Something somewhere must subscribe to it and update the other property accordingly. Something like this:

```
public abstract class ClassBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string productType;
    private string colorProductType;

    public ClassBase()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
    }

    private void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "ProductType")
        {
            // update ColorProductType here
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string ProductType
    {
        get { return productType; }
        set
        {
            if ( productType == value )
                return;

            productType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProductType");
        }
    }

    public string ColorProductType
    {
        get { return colorProductType ; }
        set
        {
            if (colorProductType == value)
                return;

            colorProductType = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ColorProductType");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Naturally, this is complete overkill. You can update `ColorProductType` when `ProductType` is updated and let the `PropertyChanged` event and databinding handle the textbox update:

```
public string ProductType
{
    get { return productType; }
    set
    {
        if ( productType == value )
            return;

        productType = value;

        // update ColorProductType here

        RaisePropertyChanged("ProductType");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs, i may have to use the overkill approach because, in my case a user can edit colorproducttype in which case there needs to be a separate property for setting colorprodtype. But whenevr the user updates the Producttype(parent's prop) it should overwrite the child's property. Are you suggesting i keep the colorprodtype property and still update the colorproducttype within Producttype?

Comment: @WittyWoman Yeah. I think the second code sample I posted should work well enough for you. I omitted `ColorProductType` from it, but you should keep it in your actual code. Then, when the user updates `ColorProductType` it will work as expected, and when the user updated `ProductType`, the code in the setter will reset `ColorProductType` as well. If you wanted to keep things more separated, you could go with the event handling approach I posted above and avoid having a side-effect of changing `ColorProductType` in your `ProductType` setter.

Comment: i wish it was as easy as updating the colorproducttype and rebinding to the child's textbox..but i need to update the bindinglist for the child to see the changes on the child when the parent is updated, so i guess i will have to use the listchanged event of the bindinglist, find the children of the parent i am changing and modify the respective properties in the list. Its pretty manual but i dont know any other way.